# Ractive Extensions for javascript - Map & Timer not available

Tags: javascript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

Import failing for map & timer operators, even though they are referenced. I've tried to move the order around for the import statements. I've also upgraded the extensions to "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.8".

Not sure what else to try, any help is appreciated.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {WebSocketService} from "../services/WebSocketService";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timer';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  providers: [WebSocketService],
  template: require('./home.component.html'),
  styles: [require('./home.component.scss')]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private websocketservice:WebSocketService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var  clientId = 10;
    console.log('Hello Home');
    let res;


    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let subscription = this.websocketservice
          .map(data => res)
          .subscribe(observer);

      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      };

    }).retryWhen((errors) => {
      return Observable.timer(3000);
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: I think you're not understanding how `Observables` work. Your `websocketservice` is a class and you can not call `.map` on it - you have to call a function from that class, that returns an `Observable`. e.g.: `let subscription = this.websocketservice.getData().map(res => res.json()).subscribe((data) => { /* code here */ });`